# can't store value of text area in database ...in comment column it store multiline

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

HTML code

```
 <textarea id="commentarea" name="S1" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
```

C# code

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

conn.Open();

string insertcmnt = "insert into Comment(Comment) values(@comment)";

   SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertcmnt, conn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", TextBoxMode.MultiLine.ToString());
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("Commented successfully");
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Is there an exception?

Comment: in database table it store `multiline` in place of text which i enter into textarea and store `singleline` if i store i.e. `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", TextBoxMode.SingleLine.ToString());`

Comment: @user3245938, I would put that problem description in the actual question so users don't have to refer to the comments to see what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the name of the MultiLine value from the TextBoxMode enum.  You should be referencing the textarea object.  Try this

```
 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", commentarea.Text);
```

Also, the textarea in the html is missing the runat attribute

```
<textarea id="commentarea" name="S1" cols="30" rows="5" runat="server"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="commentarea" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Columns="30"/>
```

Then use

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", commentArea.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text area must be inside a form provide it with an ID (say frm), also name and id for your text area also (say txtArea1) then use the following code to get the value of your textarea:

```
HtmlTextArea txtImageupload = (HtmlTextArea)(frm.FindControl("txtArea1"));
string txtval = txtImageupload.Value;
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", txtval);
```

But you can avoid all this by using a textbox control with TextMode set to MultiLine.